# Asp.net Time Input Control Suggestions

Tags: asp.net, time, input, controls

Can anyone recommend a Time Input control for an asp.net web application?

It should be able to handle the following items

- Am/Pm
- 24 Hour
- client side validation
- client side completion (if you start the hour with a 3 then jump to minute)
- one textbox (not separate textboxes for hours and minutes, or drop downs)
- ability to actually type in the time, not simply pick it
- hint text with time separator ":"

Other features that would be nice

- Ability to increase hour or minutes with arrows
- no need to rewire after a postback

Thanks in advance for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code for time entry

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartTime", "{0:t}") %>'
                                        Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStartTimeEdit" runat="server" Text="Press 'A' or 'P' to switch AM/PM"></asp:Label>

                                    <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeStartTime" runat="server" AcceptAMPM="true" MaskType="Time"
                                        Mask="99:99" MessageValidatorTip="true" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
                                        ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" UserTimeFormat="None" TargetControlID="txtStartTime"
                                        InputDirection="LeftToRight" AcceptNegative="Left">
                                    </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
                                    <cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevStartTime" runat="server" ControlExtender="meeStartTime"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtStartTime" IsValidEmpty="False" EmptyValueMessage="Time is required "
                                        InvalidValueMessage="Time is invalid" Display="Dynamic" EmptyValueBlurredText="Time is required "
                                        InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Invalid Time" ValidationGroup="MKE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at a jquery control

- [timepicker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timepicker/)

or just put a ["time" search](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=time) across all the plugins.  I've only used the datepicker but works very well.

Comment: 2. link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Just Visit the link :http://www.obout.com/calendar/calendar_datetimepicker.aspx"

and Your problem will be resolved within seconds

Comment: You should summarize or quote the linked article, links tend to decay over time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Telerik RadTimePicker